# jenkins seems to be running inside container

Tags: docker, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, pipeline

I try to configure aquascanner inside a pipeline in Jnekins using a Dockerfile and Jenkinsfile.I have installed jenkins docker-ce and docker-compose inside a virtualbox, it means that I exacute everything locally. This is the content of the tow files
Dockerfile:

```
FROM debian:jessie-slim
RUN apt-get update && apt-get -y install ca-certificates
ADD https://get.aquasec.com/microscanner /
```

Jenkinsfile

```
pipeline {
    agent { dockerfile true }
    stages {     

    stage('Scan') {
        steps{
            aquaMicroscanner imageName: 'aboullaite', notCompliesCmd: 'exit 4', onDisallowed: 'fail', outputFormat: 'html'
         }
       }  
    }
}
```

When I execute the pipeline, I get this error:

```
Démarré par l'utilisateur admin admin
Obtained Jenkinsfile from git https://github.com/mohamedoul/aquamicroscannerpipeline.git
Running in Durability level: MAX_SURVIVABILITY
[Pipeline] Start of Pipeline
[Pipeline] node
Running on Jenkins in /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/microscanneejenkinsfiledockerfile
[Pipeline] {
[Pipeline] stage
[Pipeline] { (Declarative: Checkout SCM)
[Pipeline] checkout
No credentials specified
 > git rev-parse --is-inside-work-tree # timeout=10
Fetching changes from the remote Git repository
 > git config remote.origin.url https://github.com/mohamedoul/aquamicroscannerpipeline.git # timeout=10
Fetching upstream changes from https://github.com/mohamedoul/aquamicroscannerpipeline.git
 > git --version # timeout=10
 > git fetch --tags --progress https://github.com/mohamedoul/aquamicroscannerpipeline.git +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
 > git rev-parse refs/remotes/origin/master^{commit} # timeout=10
 > git rev-parse refs/remotes/origin/origin/master^{commit} # timeout=10
Checking out Revision b3bd0c9855c96e34afefeded90a2b3c6aa1032fe (refs/remotes/origin/master)
 > git config core.sparsecheckout # timeout=10
 > git checkout -f b3bd0c9855c96e34afefeded90a2b3c6aa1032fe
Commit message: "Update Dockerfile"
 > git rev-list --no-walk 39200d7950e525aa7b1d6e539ca4182c66c8fae1 # timeout=10
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // stage
[Pipeline] withEnv
[Pipeline] {
[Pipeline] stage
[Pipeline] { (Declarative: Agent Setup)
[Pipeline] isUnix
[Pipeline] readFile
[Pipeline] sh
+ docker build -t 00302783dd2c8725d52bd0fdec5aee3bae719abb -f Dockerfile .
Sending build context to Docker daemon  212.5kB

Step 1/3 : FROM debian:jessie-slim
 ---> dc5ba56066bd
Step 2/3 : RUN apt-get update && apt-get -y install ca-certificates
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 2bac27594205
Step 3/3 : ADD https://get.aquasec.com/microscanner /

 ---> Using cache
 ---> 9ddc79a6c3f1
Successfully built 9ddc79a6c3f1
Successfully tagged 00302783dd2c8725d52bd0fdec5aee3bae719abb:latest
[Pipeline] dockerFingerprintFrom
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // stage
[Pipeline] sh
+ docker inspect -f . 00302783dd2c8725d52bd0fdec5aee3bae719abb
.
[Pipeline] withDockerContainer
Jenkins does not seem to be running inside a container
$ docker run -t -d -u 123:128 -w /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/microscanneejenkinsfiledockerfile -v /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/microscanneejenkinsfiledockerfile:/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/microscanneejenkinsfiledockerfile:rw,z -v /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/microscanneejenkinsfiledockerfile@tmp:/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/microscanneejenkinsfiledockerfile@tmp:rw,z -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** 00302783dd2c8725d52bd0fdec5aee3bae719abb cat
$ docker top a975971fc5a26ef6c02f3e4e6bc6bcad15dc75bdb773ab2bb1fd63f8036785bb -eo pid,comm
[Pipeline] {
[Pipeline] stage
[Pipeline] { (Scan)
[Pipeline] aquaMicroscanner
Aqua MicroScanner in progress...
Archiving artifacts
Archiving artifacts
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // stage
[Pipeline] }
$ docker stop --time=1 a975971fc5a26ef6c02f3e4e6bc6bcad15dc75bdb773ab2bb1fd63f8036785bb
$ docker rm -f a975971fc5a26ef6c02f3e4e6bc6bcad15dc75bdb773ab2bb1fd63f8036785bb
[Pipeline] // withDockerContainer
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // withEnv
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // node
[Pipeline] End of Pipeline
ERROR: Scanning failed.
Finished: FAILURE
```